# Монтирование iso образов дисков средствами .Net

Tags: c#, .net, iso-образ

Есть ли в .Net средства для монтирования iso образов дисков?

Comment: Спасибо! Я понял, что оказывается возможностей масса: и Win32, и PowerShell, и без монтирования, просто читать/писать с  DiscUtils.

Comment: А галку можно только одну? Но ведь может так случиться, что в разных комментариях одинаковые по значимости ответы.

Comment: Формат Stack Overflow предполагает принятие только одного наиболее верного решения.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В Windows 8/8.1/10 есть встроенная поддержка монтирования ISO, вызовом [`AttachVirtualDisk`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd323692(v=vs.85).aspx).

Но из C# диск проще всего примонтировать вызовом Powershell ([nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management.Automation)) - `Mount-DiskImage`

```
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace IsoMountTest
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var isoPath = @"C:\Foo\bar.iso";
            using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                ps.AddCommand("Mount-DiskImage").AddParameter("ImagePath", isoPath).Invoke();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

<sub>en-SO: [Is there any special API in Windows 8 to Mount ISO files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29582801/1988244)</sub>

Comment: Ещё надо подключить сборку System.Management.Automation (из системы или [через nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management.Automation/)).

Comment: @VladD да, там была ссылка на nuget в ответе, но она хорошо спряталась :)

Comment: Хм, и правда, была :) Не заметил.

Answer (score 1):

Реализовать монтирование дисков средствами .NET - нельзя (нужен драйвер, а драйвера на .NET не пишут). Но можно найти внешнюю программу и запустить ее, сказав ей примонтировать диск.

Запускается внешняя программа обычно через [`Process.Start`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(v=vs.110).aspx).

Кстати, если просто "запустить" .iso-файл - то при установленной программе для монтирования образов есть неплохой шанс, что образ смонтируется.

Comment: стоит добавить, что Win8/8.1/10 умеет монтировать iso без сторонних программ.

Answer (score 0):

Для этого есть [DiscUtils](https://discutils.codeplex.com/), есть [IsoCreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/iso-creator-cs/), также есть [IsoCS](http://isocs.codeplex.com/).

**Источники**: [enSO1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952725/create-a-cd-dvd-iso-image-in-net), [enSO2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9685894/dvd-iso-from-c-sharp-net-discutils-alternatives) и, как ни странно, [гугл](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=.net%20iso%20library).

Comment: Денис, ну и как там монтировать образ-то? :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov по первой ссылке есть кусок кода)

Comment: Денис, там нет куска кода, который бы выполнял *монтирование*. Только создание и чтение.

Answer (score 0):

Если монтирование ISO образа вам необходимо для чтения содержимого, то в монтировании нет нужды, потому что содержимое ISO файла можно прочитать так:

```
using (FileStream isoStream = File.Open(@"C:\sample.iso")) {
  CDReader cd = new CDReader(isoStream, true);
  Stream fileStream = cd.OpenFile(@"Folder\Hello.txt", FileMode.Open);
  // ...
}
```

Этот код работает благодаря проекту DiscUtils, в котором существует поддержка ISO файлов, а также для виртуальных машин есть поддержка: VHD, VDI, XVA, VMDK и многих других.
Страницы для скачивания DiscUtils:
http://www.nuget.org/packages/Discutils/
http://discutils.codeplex.com/

Comment: Вижу чтение файла из образа - но не вижу монтирования.

Comment: Вы думаете, что цель монтирования в самом монтировании? :)

Comment: Цель монтирования - дать доступ к файлу другим программам, которые знать не знают ни о образах диска, ни о монтировании.

Comment: Вы думаете, что спрашивающий разрабатывает менеджер монтирования? :) Возможно, но маловероятно, потому что в Windows есть необходимые утилиты. Я думаю, что автор хочет из своей программы получить доступ к ISO.

Comment: @Box если вы думаете что автору нужно не примонтировать ISO, а решить какую-то другую проблему - уточните это в комментариях к вопросу

Comment: Монтирование необходимо, когда надо прочитать содержимое ISO, о чем я написал в ответе. Как мне добавить комментарии к вопросу, если кнопка [добавить комментарий] отключена?